# Change CSS Dynamically in Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

Is there a way to change `css` properties asynchronously?

I have full access to `node`, `vue`, and it's to sit in a `chrome` browser, and the text I need to update the css to is various pages long, so the browser slows to a crawl while the css is applying.

```
fontSize (newSize) {
  document.getElementById('text').style.fontSize = `${newSize}px`
}
```

I need to modify it to update the page better, and I'm not sure how to go about it.  I was looking at the `async` module, but it's awfully dense and I'm not 100% sure it offers what I need.

Comment: why not just use a `:style="sizeVal + 'px'"`

Comment: Asynchronous processes improve things that are naturally IO-bound. This operation is CPU-bound. And given JS user runtime is single-threaded - you cannot improve performance of this very operation.

Comment: where `sizeVal` is a data var that you can add/subtract to prn

Comment: @Derek so I should change this `    <q-slider v-model="font.size" :min='12' :max='100' id="font-size" v-on:input="fontSize" />` to `    <q-slider v-model="font.size" :min='12' :max='100' id="font-size" :style="font.size + 'px'"  />

Comment: @ms_nitrogen yes, but be sure to define it in your `data()` portion of the component

Comment: @zerkms - I changed the title to fit more of what OP wanted

Comment: here is an article on this topic https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-styles/